# Is everything after an exporting namespace not exported?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, circular-dependency, c++-modules

I was reading about modules, and I wished to do something like this:

a.cpp

```
module foo.a;

export namespace foo {
    struct A {
        void doA();
    };
}

import foo.b;
void foo::A::doA() {
     B{}.doB();
}
```

b.cpp

```
module foo.b;

export namespace foo {
    struct B {
        void doB();
        void start();
    };
}

import foo.a;
import std.io;
void foo::B::doB() {
     std::cout << "Stuff done!" << std::endl;
}

void foo::B::start() {
     A{}.doA();
}
```

main.cpp

```
import foo.b;

int main() {
    foo::B{}.start();
}
```

Since module interfaces cannot use each other, for that to work, everything after the exported namespace must not be part of the interface. Is the above correct according to the current TS? For circular dependency in the implementation, is it required to split it into another file?

Comment: You mislabeled your code as c/c++. Please label it as Typescript.

Comment: @StarShine - What are you on about?

Comment: module, import and syntax such as A{}.doA() are, to my knowledge, not valid c++.

Comment: @StarShine - Then I suggest you update your knowledge.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok, apologies, as this is new to me. From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental I learn that this is still experimental and draft stage. Cppreference.org has the keywords listed, but there's no content behind the links yet.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I dig the humor, you're right about the tags ;) Thanks for sharing, you triggered my curiosity! Any good resources apart from the draft docs?

Comment: @StarShine - There are the CppCon talks. [Here's the one from 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwdQA0pGWa4). That's more introductory, but is probably different than the current state of the proposal. They originally aimed to add it into C++17.

Comment: @StarShine glad to hear! Here's a [guide written by the build2 developer](https://build2.org/build2/doc/build2-build-system-manual.xhtml#cxx-modules-intro). He also written [module design guidelines](https://build2.org/build2/doc/build2-build-system-manual.xhtml#cxx-modules-guidelines).

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - Seeing as the bounty period ends tomorrow, how to you feel about the posted answer?

Comment: @StoryTeller it could benefit of more explanation, but serves it's purpose. It could have quote the content of the PDTS to pinpoint the rule that forbid it, and I would gladly give him the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Working Draft, Extensions to C++ for
Modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4681.pdf) (found in [Experimental C++ Features](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental)), page 13, §10.7.2:3:

> A module `M1` has an interface dependency on a module `M2` if the module
>   interface of `M1` contains a module-import-declaration nominating `M2`. A
>   module shall not have a transitive interface dependency on itself.

Example:

```
// Interface unit of M1
export module M1;
import M2;
export struct A { };

// Interface unit of M2
export module M2;
import M3;

// Interface unit of M3
export module M3;
import M1; // error: cyclic interface dependency M3 -> M1 -> M2 -> M3
```

---

Q: "For circular dependency in the implementation, is it required to split it into another file?"

A:  Yes.

---

Q: "Is the above correct according to the current TS?"

A:  No.

In your code, you have an error, since `foo.a` and `foo.b` form a ***cyclic interface dependency***.

Comment: So the interface is the whole file, not just the exported stuff. Interesting. I guess this is because the whole interface unit must be compiled in order to produce an interface binary file.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: No, the _interface_ is just the exported items (\[dcl.module.interface]/1).  However,  it is the interface _unit_ that is restricted.

Comment: @DavisHerring ah yes, this is what I meant. I'm still not used with all those new terms!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use a separate implementation file for at least one of the modules (the one that is conceptually "lower-level").  The [PDTS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4681.pdf)'s [dcl.module.import]/3 says

> A module `M1` has an *interface dependency* on a module `M2` if the module interface of `M1` contains a *module-import-declaration* nominating `M2`. A module shall not have a transitive interface dependency on itself.

This applies regardless of the location of the *module-import-declaration*, since `export` can appear anywhere and multiple times in a module interface unit.  The rule is meant to prevent the appearance of types and templates from each of two modules in the interface of the other, since then neither could be imported "first".

Comment: Would you care to quote relevant information from the PDTS please? That would make the answer more complete.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: OK, done; not that gsamaras didn't do it first.

Comment: it's okay. You actually add some information that was missing in the other answer. It make things even more clearer. I didn't thought about reopening the export. Thanks!